# Fourier series of $f(x)=1$

Tags: fourier-series

$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}\cos nx$,

where $a_{n}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f(t)\cos(nt) \ dt$, if $f$ is even.

But for $f(x)=1$, the left side goes to $0$. How can I get the Fourier series of $1$?

Comment: The left side of what goes to 0?

Comment: Isn't it obvious that a constant function has no harmonics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function periodically over $\;[-\pi,\pi]\;$ , so being the function even we get:

$$\begin{align*}&a_0=\frac2\pi\int\limits_0^\pi dx=2\\{}\\
&a_n=\frac2\pi\int\limits_0^\pi\cos nx\;dx=\left.\frac2{n\pi}\sin nx\right|_0^\pi=0\end{align*}$$

and the Fourier series we get is pretty boring:

$$f(x)=\frac{a_0}2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cos nxdx=1$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18579/discussion-on-answer-by-timbuc-fourier-series-of-fx1).

Comment: @ArthurFischer, what is the problem with leaving a long discussion here? I don't see it but perhaps there's something I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

For $f(x)=1$,we have $a_0=2$, $a_n=b_n=0~(n=1,2,\cdots)$

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why 1=4/pi*sigma(1 to infty)[sin{(sn-1)x}]/(2n-1)?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

$$f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_m\sin(mx)$$

as $f(x)=1$ we get $$b_m=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\sin(mx)dx$$ $$=\frac{2}{\pi}[\frac{-\cos(mx)}{m}]_0^\pi=\frac{2}{m\pi}(1-(1)^m)$$

This gives us that $b_m= 0 $ if m is even, or $b_m = \frac{4}{m\pi}$ if m is odd

In this question we want to keep m odd so to unsure that we let $m =2n-1$ so this gives us $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4}{m\pi}sin(mx)$$
$$f(x)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin((2n-1)x)}{2n-1}$$

Comment: This is wrong because for $b_m$ you have to integrate over $[0,2\pi]$ and the result is zero.